# Are there demonstrations of elliptical orbits using charged spheres?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, electric-fields, charge, orbital-motion, education

The marble rolling around in a depression is certainly a nice one, but I'm not sure if it's actually elliptical.  That's a separate issue I suppose, but meanwhile I was thinking, couldn't you use two charged spheres on a nearly frictionless insulating surface to demonstrate an elliptical orbit?  (As long as speeds are slow enough to ignore magnetic effects)  Is that feasible?  Are there videos of such a demonstration?

Comment: There are all sorts of issues with keeping the rolling balls charged and preventing excessive frictional loses, but before that I suggest you put some numbers in to see what kind charges, electric fields, and voltages  you are talking about. Look up the size and mass of your chosen spheres (e.g. glass marbles, billiard balls) and then use Coulomb's law to figure out how big a charge the balls would need to have to have an orbit of a reasonable size  (r=1m?) for a demonstration.  If those numbers are not reasonable, then it isn't worth worrying about the rest of the practical details.

Comment: To know why you haven't found any, simply calculate the force between two spheres for a given voltage difference and equate to the centripetal force ;) ....then post that calculation here as the answer to your question :)